# Возможно ли дополнять Runnable по 1 команде?

Tags: java

Мой план хотелось бы как то преобразовать из строк в команды, но так как я знаю как обрабатывать строки, остается лишь как то дополнять Runnable переменную, возможно ли это сделать?

Вот пример`Runnable r = ()->{System.out.println("Hello")};`
Я хочу туда внедрить несколько команд. Чтобы результатом было напримере если добавить несколько команд содержалось:
`()->{int a = 10;System.out.print(a);System.out.println("Hello")};`

Comment: Можете более понятно изложить, что вы хотите? Желательно с примерами кода.

Comment: Вот ввел. Еще чтото надо?

Comment: Просто пишете там несколько инструкций. `Runnable r = ()->{System.out.println("Hello")};System.out.println("Hell")};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        int a = 10;
        System.out.print(a);
        System.out.println("Hello")};
    }
}
```

Comment: Чтобы его не в компиляторе писать а сразу в саму во внутрь, как :`r.add(System.out.println("hello"));`

Comment: Нет, так не получится. Runnable это обычный интерфейс с методом run. Нельзя просто взять и и добавить инструкций в метод во время выполнения программы.

Comment: Я просто хотел бы создать, чтото типо интерпретатора, который бы исполнял команды по строкам, без компиляции

Comment: Это делается иначе и несколько сложнее.

Comment: Жалко... Ну так хотябы спасибо за ответ, что невозможно. А так хотелось это сделать, ну ладно уж.